# How to choose size of thread pool on android

Tags: java, android

I want to read multiple files from the sdcard in parallel with a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. What is the best way to choose number of `Threads`? Is it okay to choose the size based on the number of available processors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choosing the number of `Threads` based on the number of processors is a pretty good solution because it scales based on the hardware of the device which is running the app. A good example of this can be found in the [**source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/os/AsyncTask.java) of `AsyncTask`:

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};

private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);

public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

I would consider this a best practice solution.

You can look at the source code of `AsyncTask` [**here**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/os/AsyncTask.java) if you want a better idea of how they use the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Xavar Kapeller, why do you use LinkedBlockingQueue size 128.?I am facing *java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:* exception. Can I use maximum size Integer.MAX_VALUE..?

Comment: @patelvatsal Yes you can - by `Integer.MAX_VALUE` might be a little excessive. If you expect your work queue to be larger than `128` at any point you have to increase that value to an appropriate amount.

Comment: .Thank you for your advice.!